# Java file downloader not working

Tags: java

I've create this function...

```
void DownloadFromDatabase() throws IOException {
            URL website = new URL("http://theurlofmywebsite.org/databases/record_file.txt");

            ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(website.openStream());
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("record_file.txt");

            fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
        }
```

... and I call it when I click a button as you can see here.

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

try {

            DownloadFromDatabase();

        } catch (IOException ex) {

           Logger.getLogger(xGrep.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

        }
}
```

When I click the button, `DownloadFromDatabase();` is called but I don't see the file `record_file.txt` on my desktop. Do you know why?

Comment: No - but as you're swallowing all `IOException`s without logging them at all, my guess is that one is happening and you're ignoring it. You should almost **never** swallow exceptions like that. (Additionally, you should follow Java naming conventions, and indent your code more readably.)

Comment: and then? what could I do with the code?

Comment: Well once you've logged the exception, you'll have a much better idea of what's going wrong. For example, maybe you don't have write access to the local file. Or maybe it's failing in the HTTP transfer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is not the best, but I've made a test on my computer and it works. It downloads a text file with 500 lines in 2 seconds.

```
void DownloadFromDatabase() throws MalformedURLException, IOException {

     URLConnection conn = new URL("your_url_here").openConnection();

     InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
     OutputStream outstream = new FileOutputStream(new File("filename.txt"));

     byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
     int len;

     while ((len = is.read(buffer)) > 0) {
      outstream.write(buffer, 0, len);
     }
     outstream.close();
     }
```

I've named it `DownloadFromDatabase()` so you only have to copy/paste this code instead of yours. Also, pay attention with the exceptions.

Comment: where does it download the file?

Comment: Where you want. Look at there: new File("filename.txt"). Type for example C://folder1//folder2//filename.txt to get the path you want :)